# How can I save Parse Tree Visualization as Image in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, antlr4, parse-tree

I've installed Antlr4 plugin and use Parse Tree visualization in Eclipse. I want to know How I can save the Parse Tree figure as image ?
I'm using Eclipse Mars Release (4.5.0).

for example  as you can see, there is a big parse Tree which can't be seen in the window without scrolling.there isn't any zoom in zoom out tools.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is ANTLR4 SDK available here:-
https://github.com/jknack/antlr4ide

This has a view called 'Syntax Diagram' which provides the option to save the diagram as a html file with multiple images.